# Angular2 how to pass *ngFor iterated item to pipe as parameter?

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

Suppose I have bellow code:

```
<a *ngFor="let sterm; of data?.search_term | getOtherSearchTerms: sterm" href="job_search_results.do?jkw=">{{sterm}}</a>
```

and here is my pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'getOtherSearchTerms'
})

export class SearchTermPipe implements PipeTransform {
  otherSearchTerms;

  transform(searchTermArray: Array<any>, currentTerm: any): any {
    console.log(searchTermArray);
    console.log(currentTerm);
    return searchTermArray;
  }
}
```

and the log is like this:[image]

As you see `sterm` is not passed to the pipe.

Note: The main goal of using pipe here is to get all the other array elements except current value(for example in first loop i want to get all other words inside array except `Software`, and on second loop all other words except `Engineering` and the same for else.)

Note: `sterm` should be `Software` on first iteration, and `Engineering` on second iterate.

I want to create some think like this:

Want to create `<a>` tag for each keywords inside array, but pass all other words as query string to `a` tag. for example:

```
<a href="job_search_results.do?jkw=engineering+keyword2">Software</a>
<a href="job_search_results.do?jkw=software+keyword2">Engineering</a>
<a href="job_search_results.do?jkw=software+engineering">Keyword2</a>
```

Comment: Can you try it with removing `;` from `*ngFor="let sterm;` ?

Comment: looks like code should be like this `*ngFor="let sterm of data?.search_term` , without semicolon

Comment: @echonax I have checked without `;`, but has the same problem.

Comment: @PardeepJain my first code was without `;`, but has the same problem

Comment: problem might be diff. but no need to add `;` it's wrong way

Comment: There is no `sterm` yet within the `*ngFor="..."` expression, only outside of it, and it also wouldn't make any sense. Not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to modify individual items using a pipe, this should do what you want:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let sterm of data?.search_term">
  <a href="job_search_results.do?jkw=">{{sterm | getOtherSearchTerms}}</a>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: But this time `<a>` tag is created more than two times, for example for my data 4 `<a>` is created.

Comment: I didn't understand what you try to accomplish. What is "the current value" you mention in your explanation. Please provide more information about how the result should look like.

Comment: hat is "all other words". I still don't understand what you try to accomplish.

Comment: I want to have a way to call `pipe` inside `href` and assign `pipe` returned data to the `?jkw=`

Comment: This is all some abstract explanation I can't make any sense of. Please make the description more concret. If the data is x and it gets passed to y I want the result look like z where x, y, and z are concrete examples of your data.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let sterm of data?.search_term">
   <a [href]="sterm | getOtherSearchTerms:data?.search_term">{{ sterm }}</a>
 </ng-container>
```

and change your `pipe` to this:

```
transform(currentTerm: any, searchTermArray: Array<any>): any {
   return 'job_search_results.do?jkw='+searchTermArray;
}
```